# Adding Total Items of Related List to Other Fields of Master Object

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have two custom objects **Object1__c** (Master) and **Object2__c** (Detail). I am currently using a roll-up summary field (**Total__c**) in Object1__c to get and display the total items from Object2__c. I don't have any problems with this.

But recently, the client wants to add another custom field to Object1__c. It is named **Delivery_Fee__c**, having Number as the data type. Delivery fee is not fixed, thus they need to input it manually. This delivery fee must be added to the total line items.

I know that roll-up summary field only works for objects with M-D relationship. For workaround, I created a custom formula field (**Final_Total_Amount__c**) in Object1__c that adds both the value from **Total__c** and **Delivery_Fee__c**. But what I'm really aiming at is just to have one field to hold all the total items from the detail object and the delivery field from the master object.

How can I do this using apex trigger or apex class?

Comment: Use Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary (free) package to rollup across lookup relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a separate field for the delivery fee, you can also do a roll up summary on the Delivery_Fee__c using a trigger that rolls up to the Master Object record. Since it's a formula field, it sounds like you might also want to do the calculation in the trigger rather than using the formula. Otherwise it could slow down your trigger if you also want to get the Total__c.

There's a free App Exchange product that may do at least some of what you want called [Roll-up Helper](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI) that can be used for a limited number of fields after which you'll have to buy a license. To "roll your own", you can start by using code from @AndrewFawcett [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) repository on Github.

Comment: yes i intend to do all the computation in the trigger. the total_amount__c formula field from Object1__c is just a workaround, since I'm not really sure on how to execute it using apex trigger

Comment: So, was your question then how to write a roll-up summary trigger?

Comment: yes, that's exactly I'll put it. I've been practicing with simple triggers, but it seems creating roll-up summary programmatically which involves also field from master object in the computation is not so simple